# How to show simulator logs? in IOS 12.0 & Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10, ios12

How to check simulator logs? I am running project in Xcode 10 and simulator iPad (6th generation) 12.0

I have checked in Xcode-> Window -> Devices and simulators -> select "simulator" 
But not showing simulator log

also i have checked in Simulator -> Debug -> Open system log...
But not showing simulator log

Comment: see this may be its helps you : https://medium.com/@ankitkumargupta/ios-simulator-command-line-tricks-ee58054d30f4

Comment: What happens when you click "Open System Log..." in the Simulator's Debug menu?

Comment: It is not showing my logs which is i have written in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" using print("").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found solution for this issue, Open system console log on MAC

⌘ + space and type "console" -> press "Enter" to open system console log then select your simulator

You can see only log which is log using

> NSLog("MyLog")

But, You can not see log which is write with `print("MyLog")`

Comment: `print()` output is written to stdout, which is not always hooked up to anything when you launch an application. You can use `xcrun simctl launch` to observe stdout from a launched application, though normally Xcode will also show this to via View, Debug Area, Activate Console.

Comment: This is the only place where I actually found how to see log messages from the simulator, since the Show Log button is not there anymore on the devices and simulators window.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `os_log` function and checking the log in Console.app on Mac